# (intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function in async for of

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I have a huge algorithm that currently creates a list of objects filters a subarray, turns that array to a csv, the pdf file associated with that object and emails them to the right person.

Many of those functions work in  harmony already.  But an issue I keep running into is once I get async data back the next loop I need to run hangs half way through the second trip around. Ive had to contain  a very very large block of code into one for of for this iteration to work.  So  maybe someone can look at it and see why the loop breaks down or how I can piece meal the loops that follow the async filter call.

I will try to truncate the blocks that are within the for of as best as possible, but its quite long.

```
const updatedDrop = []
async function withForOf() {
  for (const tollFree of drop) {

//define terms of tollFree

   zips = await Zip.find({
    "class": { "$in": tollFree.zipCodes },
  });  

//multiple case switches that do the filtering

switch (zipCodeSuppress) {
  case "keepSelect":
    updatedList = mailList.filter((e) => zips.includes(e.zip4.substring(0,5)))
    break;
  case "suppressSelect":
    updatedList = mailList.filter((e) => !zips.includes(e.zip4.substring(0,5)))
    break;  
}
 const  dropItem = {
        updatedList,
        tracking,
        vendor,
        postageCeiling,
        combinedCost,
        unitCost,
        mailHouse,
        date,
        title, 
     }       
    updatedDrop.push(dropItem)
  }

//this is generally where it breaks down for the second instance of Toll Free, where i remap the list to  only include certain values
let result = []
  updatedDrop.forEach((drop) => {
    drop.updatedList.map((list, i) =>
      result[i]
        ? (result[i].fullName = list.fullName)(
            (result[i].First_Name = list.firstName)
          )((result[i].Last_Name = list.lastName))(
            (result[i].Delivery_Address = list.deliveryAddress)
          )((result[i].City = list.city))((result[i].State = list.state))(
            (result[i].Zip_4 = list.zip4)
          )((result[i].County = list.county))(
            (result[i].File_Type = list.fileType)
          )((result[i].Amount = list.amount))(
            (result[i].pinCode = list.pinCode)
          )(
            (result[i].Five_Amount = (parseFloat(list.amount) * 0.05).toFixed(
              2
            ))
          )(
            (result[i].Nine_Amount = (parseFloat(list.amount) * 0.95).toFixed(
              2
            ))
          )
        : (result[i] = {
            Full_Name: list.fullName,
            First_Name: list.firstName,
            Last_Name: list.lastName,
            Delivery_Address: list.deliveryAddress,
            City: list.city,
            State: list.state,
            Zip_4: list.zip4,
            County: list.county,
            File_Type: list.fileType,
            Amount: list.amount,
            Pin_Code: list.pinCode,
            Five_Amount: (parseFloat(list.amount) * 0.05).toFixed(2),
            Nine_Amount: (parseFloat(list.amount) * 0.95).toFixed(2),
          })
    );
} withForOf() 
})
```

the rest of the function just sends that list and csv off. I read that maybe it has to do with a missing semi colon, if thats the case im willing to post the entire bed if someone wants to look for where its  missing.

does it maybe have something to do with nesting the foreach in a for of? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not recommend to use `await` in a for loop because it will block the main thread. You can use the `async` library to iterate asynchronously, or better yet use map or reduce.

Comment: @doublesharp, do you have a source for that? I thought `await` does not block the main thread if it's a loop

Comment: i got feed back to switch to a for of and spicier still is the ecma 2018 await for of  or whatever.

Comment: If I can make suggestion is I would clean up the map function just so its more readable. I see your trying to do an implicit return but I think that might be messing something up. I think if you abstract out that ternary the code will be a bit more manageable so it will be easier to help.

Comment: @GrantHerman i think you are on to something, because i blocked off everything going  into that im reading the list lengths correctly. so how can i reformat that list with map without ternary? because ive only ever been exposed to that.

Comment: @MickeyGray, it looks like the culprit is the section that starts with `(result[i].fullName = list.fullName)(...`. This is not the correct syntax for running multiple statements in a row. You should also change `map` to a `forEach`

Comment: Yeah @MickeyGray its confusing so your checking if result[i] is an object and then setting all of those values from the list or if it doesent exist you want to set the result[i] to be that object. couldnt you just cut out the middle man and just set all result[i] to that big object you have

Comment: @Steve i misspoke a bit, it doesn't fully block the thread but doesn't fully take advantage of parallelization: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop